# Why my ColumnAttribute are not used when fetching data from a View via SqlQuery with Entity Framework 6.x?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am struggling to properly fetch data from a SQL view using the DbContext and the entity below:

```
public class StagingDbContext : ApplicationDbContext
{
    private const string AssignmentQuery =
        @"SELECT DISTINCT " +
        @"[Region], " +
        @"[Technician], " +
        @"[Email], " + 
        @"[On Call Group], " + 
        @"[Manager], " + 
        @"[Manager Email] " +
        @"FROM [Staging].[dbo].[Assignment] " +
        @"WHERE " + 
        @"[Technician] IS NOT NULL AND " +
        @"[Technician] NOT LIKE 'DECOMMISSIONED' " +
        @"AND [Technician] NOT LIKE 'N/A' " +
        @"AND [Technician] NOT LIKE '4242NAH%' " +
        @"AND [Region] IS not Null " +
        @"AND [On Call Group] NOT LIKE 'N/A' " +
        @"AND [On Call Group] NOT LIKE 'Decommisioned'";

    public IEnumerable<Assignment> Assignments => Database.SqlQuery<Assignment>(AssignmentQuery);

    public StagingDbContext ()
        : base(nameof(StagingDbContext ))
    {
    }
}

[Table("Assignment")]
public class Assignment
{
    [Column("Region")]
    public string Region { get; set; }

    [Column("SiteID")]
    public string SiteId { get; set; }

    [Column("Technician")]
    public string Technician { get; set; }

    [Column("Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Column("On Call Group")]
    public string OnCallGroup { get; set; }

    [Column("Manager Email")]
    public string ManagerEmail { get; set; }
}
```

My issue arises when it comes to the property names that does not match exactly the ones provided in the query, I thought that the `ColumnAttribute` was taken in account but apparently this is not really the case.

My current workaround is to basically rename columns in my SQL query ([Column Name] AS ColumnName in order to make them match directly to the property names of my entity (e.g. removing white space characters) but I found it a bit awkward to rewrite the Query exclusively for that particular purpose.

Is there anything that can be done to force the `SqlQuery` to the names provided by my `ColumnAttribute`s instead of the properties?

[EDIT]
It was more or less already answered somewhere else:

- [Entity framework Code First - configure mapping for SqlQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733047/entity-framework-code-first-configure-mapping-for-sqlquery)
- [Entity Framework using Database.SqlQuery() where column names are invalid C# member names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770766/entity-framework-using-database-sqlquery-where-column-names-are-invalid-c-shar)
- [Object Mapping from stored procedure using the columnname attribute in EntityFramework CodeFirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612901/object-mapping-from-stored-procedure-using-the-columnname-attribute-in-entityfra)
- [How to use Entity Framework to map results of a stored procedure to entity with differently named parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929113/how-to-use-entity-framework-to-map-results-of-a-stored-procedure-to-entity-with)
- [getting Entity Framework raw query to respect attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573206/getting-entity-framework-raw-query-to-respect-attributes)

Comment: May be, at this case, you can try to get abstract `object`'s list and then convert it to desired presentation: `var AssignmentsDto = Database.SqlQuery<object>(AssignmentQuery); var Assignments = ConvertViaReflection(AssignmentsDto);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My current workaround is to basically rename columns in my SQL query ([Column Name] AS ColumnName in order to make them match directly to the property names of my entity (e.g. removing white space characters) but I found it a bit awkward to rewrite the Query exclusively for that particular purpose.

Yes it is really awkward but, as far as I know, this is the only way.

The feature you are seeking (using the mapping configuration for mapping a SqlQuery/Stored Procedure result to entities) does not exist in EF 6.x, and [will not be implemented](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/233?PendingVoteId=233)

Comment: Your *will not be implemented* link is no longer valid.